# Java 8 lambda sum, count and group by

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Select sum(paidAmount), count(paidAmount), classificationName,
From tableA
Group by classificationName;
```

How can i do this in Java 8 using streams and collectors?

Java8:

```
lineItemList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bucket::getBucketName,
                       Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                                           Bucket::getPaidAmount,
                                           BigDecimal::add)))
```

This gives me sum and group by. But how can I also get count on the group name ?

Expectation is :

```
100, 2, classname1 
50, 1, classname2
150, 3, classname3
```

Comment: can you elaborate or give me example please

Answer (score 6):

Using an extended version of the `Statistics` class of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48391081/2711488),

```
class Statistics {
    int count;
    BigDecimal sum;

    Statistics(Bucket bucket) {
        count = 1;
        sum = bucket.getPaidAmount();
    }
    Statistics() {
        count = 0;
        sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }

    void add(Bucket b) {
        count++;
        sum = sum.add(b.getPaidAmount());
    }

    Statistics merge(Statistics another) {
        count += another.count;
        sum = sum.add(another.sum);
        return this;
    }
}
```

you can use it in a Stream operation like

```
Map<String, Statistics> map = lineItemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bucket::getBucketName,
        Collector.of(Statistics::new, Statistics::add, Statistics::merge)));
```

this may have a small performance advantage, as it only creates one `Statistics` instance per group for a sequential evaluation. It even supports parallel evaluation, but you’d need a very large list with sufficiently large groups to get a benefit from parallel evaluation.

For a sequential evaluation, the operation is equivalent to

```
lineItemList.forEach(b ->
    map.computeIfAbsent(b.getBucketName(), x -> new Statistics()).add(b));
```

whereas merging partial results after a parallel evaluation works closer to the example already given in the linked answer, i.e.

```
secondMap.forEach((key, value) -> firstMap.merge(key, value, Statistics::merge));
```

Answer (score 5):

As you're using `BigDecimal` for the amounts (which is the correct approach, IMO), you can't make use of [`Collectors.summarizingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-), which summarizes count, sum, average, min and max in one pass.

Alexis C. has already shown in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390370/1876620) one way to do it with streams. Another way would be to write your own collector, as shown in [Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48398653/1876620).

Here I'll show another way. First let's create a container class with a helper method. Then, instead of using streams, I'll use common `Map` operations.

```
class Statistics {
    int count;
    BigDecimal sum;

    Statistics(Bucket bucket) {
        count = 1;
        sum = bucket.getPaidAmount();
    }

    Statistics merge(Statistics another) {
        count += another.count;
        sum = sum.add(another.sum);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, you can make the grouping as follows:

```
Map<String, Statistics> result = new HashMap<>();
lineItemList.forEach(b -> 
    result.merge(b.getBucketName(), new Statistics(b), Statistics::merge));
```

This works by using the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method, whose docs say:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce pairs where the keys would hold the sum and the values would hold the count:

```
Map<String, SimpleEntry<BigDecimal, Long>> map = 
    lineItemList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Bucket::getBucketName,
                         reducing(new SimpleEntry<>(BigDecimal.ZERO, 0L), 
                                  b -> new SimpleEntry<>(b.getPaidAmount(), 1L), 
                                  (v1, v2) -> new SimpleEntry<>(v1.getKey().add(v2.getKey()), v1.getValue() + v2.getValue()))));
```

although `Collectors.toMap` looks cleaner:

```
Map<String, SimpleEntry<BigDecimal, Long>> map = 
    lineItemList.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Bucket::getBucketName,
                               b -> new SimpleEntry<>(b.getPaidAmount(), 1L),
                               (v1, v2) -> new SimpleEntry<>(v1.getKey().add(v2.getKey()), v1.getValue() + v2.getValue())));
```